# NodeJS write to stdin in jest tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, integration-testing, jestjs

I have a command-line app that reads user input from `stdin`:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  doSomething();
});
```

To write integration tests, I need to be able to write to `stdin` to activate the `'line'` event. However, calling `` process.stdin.write(`abc${os.EOL}`) `` in my test case produces an error (since the stream is unidirectional read-only):

> This socket is closed

How should I resolve this?

Is the only option to skip the command-line integration testing and test `doSomething` only?

Comment: this isnt happening in my case. I am simply using process.stdout.write in the try block. Am I do something different that what you are doing?

Comment: @Ammar this isn't related to `process.stdout`. Try `process.stdin.write`.

Comment: why do need to write to stdin? why cant you simply call the function? stdin.write can only be done when the input stream is paused(rl.pause())

Comment: @Ammar I need to simulate the `'line'` event for integration testing.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be possible. :(

Answer (score 0):

The `readline` library is additional layer on top of `EventEmitter`

Given `EventEmitter` is node core module with its own test coverage and `readline` with its own - I would rely on this and not to worry about bugs there that match.

I would only write test to cover logic in my code, `doSomething();` in this example